# Primefaces 3.5 not rendering line chart

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, java-ee-6

I'm trying to make a simple line chart following the Primefaces showcase example, but with no success. The xhtml page is rendering an empty div. I've changed the bean scope and still not working. Here is my code:

```
@Named(value = "chartBean")
@RequestScoped
public class ChartBean {

    private CartesianChartModel categoryModel;

    public ChartBean() {  
        createCategoryModel(); 
    }  

    private void createCategoryModel() {  
        categoryModel = new CartesianChartModel();  

        ChartSeries boys = new ChartSeries();  
        boys.setLabel("Boys");  

        boys.set("2004", 120);  
        boys.set("2005", 100);  
        boys.set("2006", 44);  
        boys.set("2007", 150);  
        boys.set("2008", 25);  

        ChartSeries girls = new ChartSeries();  
        girls.setLabel("Girls");  
        girls.set("2004", 52);  
        girls.set("2005", 60);  
        girls.set("2006", 110);  
        girls.set("2007", 135);  
        girls.set("2008", 120);  

        categoryModel.addSeries(boys);  
        categoryModel.addSeries(girls);  
    }  

    public CartesianChartModel getCategoryModel() {
        return categoryModel;
    }

    public void setCategoryModel(CartesianChartModel categoryModel) {
        this.categoryModel = categoryModel;
    }  
}
```

And my xhtml file:

```
<p:lineChart id="linear" value="#{chartBean.categoryModel}" legendPosition="e"  
                             title="Linear Chart" minY="0" maxY="10" style="height:300px">
 </p:lineChart>
```

I was using a facelets model client and now testing a simple xhtml file it works. But I need to use the client and the chart still not appearing on it. Any suggest?

Comment: I have solved the issue. I was using a script to fadeIn the page after it loads and was having a conflict with Primefaces rendering. I removed the display:none property and solved the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue. I was using a script to fadeIn the page after it loads and was having a conflict with Primefaces rendering. I removed the display:none property and solved the question!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem then I wrapped the `p:linechart` with the `p:panel` and it worked!

Like this:

```
<p:panel header="Header">  
    <p:lineChart id="linear" value="#{chartBean.categoryModel}" legendPosition="e"  
        title="Linear Chart" minY="0" maxY="10" style="height:300px"/>
</p:panel>
```

Comment: I don't know why, but at the Primefaces user's guide's FAC there is a question about charts problem.
"5. Some components like charts do not work in Safari or Chrome but there’s no problem with Firefox. The common reason is the response mimeType when using with PrimeFaces. You need to make sure responseType is "text/html". You can use the <f:view contentType="text/html"> to enforce this."
Actually I was looking up examples then I find that one that linechart is wrapped with panel and it worked and just it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried chartBean with view scope ??? 
Try with this....

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ChartBean implements Serializable
{
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L
...
```

Comment: I tried this, too. When I run it I get the following browser console message: "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead."